# Uploading an imaged modified with mini_magick (in mem) to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I need to be able to store an image to S3 without writing it to a temporary file. My application will be deployed to heroku which has a read only file system. Is there a way to save the image directly to S3 from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go it:

```
 AWS::S3::S3Object.store('image_name.png',  image.to_blob, 'bucket_name')
```

Comment: I don't understand, how does this work when you're passing in `'image_name.png'` -- doesn't that mean the image was already saved?